# Adding content between form in Formset_Factory = Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am working on a django application and more specifically, a formset (group of forms). I have the form set amount set the number of objects retrieved by a query set. What I want to do is make a change to the form set so that in between each of the forms in the formset, include a name for a user related to the form set. What is happening right now is that it is print the entire formset then the names that I want to move to be placed in between each of the forms in the formset.

** updated **.

Now what is happening is that between each of the different forms that are being iterated, It is displaying all of the objects that are being displayed. My issue is that I only want the first object in the list to print before the first form, second objects to display before the second form. and so on...

Sample of what is happening:

```
Add expense - restructured group
Please complete the form below

josh
lifter
omar
Amount: 0
Description: expense

josh
lifter
omar
Amount: 0
Description: expense

josh
lifter
omar
Amount: 0
Description: expense

submit
```

I want it to just display the first name for first form and so on. Here is the code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Add expense - {{ currentGroup.name }}</h2>
  {% if message %}
    <p>{{message}}</p>
  {% endif %}
  <form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.management_form }}
    {% for f in form %}
      {% for expense in expenses %}
        <p>{{ expense.user.username }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
      {{ f.as_p }}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate form var in template and can add information between form but make sure you have to add `{{ form.management_form }}` also in form like below code

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.management_form }}
    {% for f in form %}
    {# Add whatever information you want to show between forms #}
    {{ f.as_p }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for expense in expenses %}
      <p>{{ expense.user.username }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. but now I have another question. I messed with it but now it is iterating through the entire list of objects between each of the differet fields. please check update question... @neerajkumar

Comment: if you look at the updated section of orignal post, I implimented the method you had. I have three forms and three users. It is currently iterating though all of the objects in the list between each of the forms that is created. So all users then form, all users than form, and so on. I want to find a way to have user then form, user then form, and so on not all users then form. I updated the original post. @neerajkumar

Comment: does that help you understand

Comment: Which var iterate users in template?

Comment: oh the user is an an object that is stored in the expense table. So it is located within the expense. The username comes form `for expense in expenses` and the displaying username comes from `expense.user.username`. @neerajkumar